# Calculate difference between datetime and convert to int

Tags: c#, datetime

I have difference between DateTime

I calculate it in models

```
public partial class Park
{
    public int parkId { get; set; }
    public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
    public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeStart { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> TimeEnd { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public TimeSpan? Difference { get { return TimeEnd - TimeStart; } }
}
```

And after this I call it in back-end

```
 var items = ctx.Parks.AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new {
                    lng = x.Longitude,
                    lat = x.Latitude,
                    difference = x.Difference
                }).ToList();
```

But I get this `{ lng = 50.4558539000, lat = 30.5148783000, difference = {00:05:00} }`

If I use `TotalMinutes`, have this

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1061  'TimeSpan?' does not contain a definition for 'TotalMinutes' and no extension method 'TotalMinutes' accepting a first argument of type 'TimeSpan?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) GoogleMapsAsp_Net   C:\Users\nemes\source\repos\GoogleMapsAsp_Net\GoogleMapsAsp_Net\Controllers\HomeController.cs   28  Active

But I need the difference in minutes in `int`, how I can do this?

Comment: You want the number of days between two dates?

Comment: Well what units do you want? What result would you expect for a 5 minute difference? A 5 second difference? A 5 hour difference?

Comment: Specifically what *int* value should `00:05:00` be?

Comment: `I need diffrence in int` means in minute/seconds/milliseconds?

Comment: What do yo mean by int, if you mean seconds then use TotalSeconds property of Timespan class

Comment: @marc_spencer: Have you taken a look at the exact object that you're using?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx

Comment: @JonSkeet the duplicate marked question is not about nullable `TimeSpan` types - invalid duplicate mark

Comment: @Toshi: I didn't vote to close it as a duplicate - I voted to close for being unclear. (At the time I voted to close, there was no indication that minutes were required. It's still unclear as the OP hasn't given any requirements about what to do if `TimeStart`, `TimeEnd` or both are null.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you can do either:

```
difference = (int?)(x.Difference?.TotalMinutes)
```

in which case your answer will be a nullable int (`int?`), so it will support the possibility of the difference being null (and be null itself in that case).

Or, if you need to have a default value in that case, say `-1`, do this:

```
difference = (int)(x.Difference?.TotalMinutes ?? -1)
```

Further reading:

1. [Null propagation operator](https://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/)
2. [?? operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operator)

Comment: Actually, [`TotalMinutes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) will return a double, not in int.

Comment: You're right, was doing this from memory. Fixed.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [TotalSeconds](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds(v=vs.110).aspx) / [TotalMinutes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalminutes(v=vs.110).aspx) / etc property of `TimeSpan`.

```
 var items = ctx.Parks.AsEnumerable().Select(
                x => new {
                    lng = x.Longitude,
                    lat = x.Latitude,
                    difference = x.Difference.TotalSeconds //Just add .TotalSeconds
                }).ToList();
```

Note that, you will have to cast your `TimeSpan?` to `TimeSpan`

Comment: `I need diffrence in int` : will it mean op needs the output in seconds?